# Input Field text field cursor is missing in IOS 12 with Webview?

Tags: webview, ios12

On Webview of my website Cursor is not showing in input field.

Laravel /HTML

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: somehow, setting "user-select: none;" affects caret display in some devices. had to set "user-select:all;" for it to show up

Answer (score 4):

I changed the ***tint color*** of the view from ***white*** to ***default*** *(or any other color)*, then the cursor started showing up. I am not sure but maybe the tint color was being ignored for iOS versions less than 12. Hope this solves your issue as well.

[image]